# How to write this piece of code without AppendTo

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to fill a vector starting from component 11 from another vector, I use this code:

```
Do[AppendTo[xp, x[[i + 10]]], {i, 1, 99982}]
```

How can I fill `xp` without using `AppendTo'?

Comment: …`xp=x[[11;;99992]]`?

Comment: Not totally sure if this is what you want: `xp=x[[10;;]]`, maybe

Comment: You can use `xp={};Do[xp=Join[xp,{x[[i+10]]}],{i,1,9982}]`. It works much faster than with `AppendTo`.

Comment: @Rom38 I'm not sure why that works faster for you. I don't think it should because it still has the same problem as OP's solution. That is, growing the size of the array (i.e. allocating more memory) on every update. That's what's slow. `AppendTo` and `Join` both have this problem. Solutions that don't have this result are i.e. bags, `Sow`, pre-allocating memory and assigning using `Part`. In practice, it often turns out that growing the list dynamically is unnecessary, or can be solved by using e.g. `Table` which pre-allocates memory, but we can't tell if that is possible without context.

Comment: @C.E. You can test with long enough list, it is easy. The `Join` works faster.

Comment: @Rom38 I may not have expressed myself very clearly. I don’t doubt your report. However, it is suprising to me, and I suspect that there are solutions that are even faster than `Join` because `Join` does not fix what I consider to be the underlying problem. I wouldn’t want OP to think that it is `AppendTo` that’s the problem - while it is in this case slower than `Join` the real problem is incrementally building lists, which you should never do. (If one has to incrementally collect something, one should use bags.)

Comment: You could also try something like this ```{xp,x}//Flatten```

Comment: @Rom38 `AppendTo` is faster than your `Join` code for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KIHZh.png

Answer (score 2):

If you want xp just to be the values of x from component 11 you can use
`xp = x[[11;;]]`.
If xp is already defined, has some values and you want to append the values of x, starting from component 11 then
`Join[ xp , x[[11;;]] ]` should do the trick.